# In Xcode, is it possible to hide the timestamps that appear in the debug console when using the new Logger struct?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, logging

Calling methods for the log levels will log to a logarchive file (according to their persistence behavior) which we can view and filter in Console.app. They will also log to the Xcode debug console, displaying whatever message we handed the method, along with a giant prepended including the timestamp, app name, and category.

Is there a way to modify the output seen in the debug console to only include our message while still using Logger--specifically for iOS?